# Not getting the updated session value after postback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, session

**Objective:** I want to show loader after Report download.
For this I created a function which continuously check the session value, if the session value is "true", I hide the loader means the report has been generated else continuously showing the loader. Find the below code of this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var interval = 0;
        var session = '';
// called when click on ViewReport button
        function StartCheckingLoaderSessionValue() {
            interval = setInterval(function() { CheckLoaderSessionValue() }, 1000)
        }


        function CheckLoaderSessionValue() {
            session = '<%= Session["IsReportGenerated"]%>'
            alert(session);
            if (session == "false") {
                document.getElementById("divLoader").style.display = 'block';
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("divLoader").style.display = 'none';
                clearInterval(interval);
            }
</script>
```

Below is the method which generates a excel report file on *ViewReport* button click

```
private void DownloadExcelFile(string m_strFileName)
    {
        try
        {
            string PathToExcelFile = m_strFileName;
            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(PathToExcelFile);
            string ff = file.Name.Replace(".xlsm",".xls");
            if (file.Exists)
            {
                Response.Clear();
                Response.ClearHeaders();
                Response.ClearContent();
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename="+ff+"");
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/Excel");
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
                Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
                //Response.Flush();
                HttpContext.Current.Session["IsReportGenerated"] = "true";
                //HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
                Response.End();
                Response.Close();
                Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
                Random r = new Random();
                int rid = r.Next();
            }
            else
            {      
            }
        }
        finally
        {           

        }
    }
```

In the above method I have set the value of *Session["IsReportGenerated"] = "true"* which means the report has been generated and as you can see in my javascript code I am hiding my *divLoader*.

But the issue is that in the *alert(session)* I am always getting *"false"* not getting "true" after *ViewReport* button click.

**NOTE:** I can't use *UpdateProgress* beacuse this function is on another page, so I never get the postback complete event on the same page.

If this issue is related to postback. Please help.

Thanks In advance.

Comment: Once the response page is sent, its content won't be updated by the server. The js `session` variable will always have the same value. I suggest you to use some kind of ajax.

Comment: Any other way to achieve my objective??